# Rails support folder. Do I have to include the module it in my test_helper or is it automatic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I have this module written in my test/support folder.

```
module YourHelper
  def register_user(user)
    visit home_page
    fill_in 'user_name', :with => user.username
    fill_in 'password', :with => user.password
    click_button 'sign_up_button'
  end
end
```

Should I put it in my test/support folder or my test/helper folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a line like this in your `rails_helper.rb` or `spec_helper.rb` and it will auto require all your support files

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("test/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
```

Comment: What are the **/* for? My files sit right inside the support folder. Do I need both sets of *? Why are there two asterisks? Why is there 1 asterisk after the /?

Comment: the double `**` is just to include nested folders too, in case you group them into folders in the future, like `test/support/users/user_helper.rb` for example

Comment: So right now if my modules sit right inside the support folder and are not nested... will the method you gave me with Dir not find the files that are sitting in the top level of the support folder?

Comment: this line finds all files inside `test/support` and inside folders that are inside that folder, so you don't need to worry, `test/support/**/*.rb` still can match `test/support/file.rb`